# non negative solution of the matrix equation $A^T U A = U - C$ if C is non-negative

Tags: matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Given $A$ a matrix with spectral radius smaller than 1 and a matrix $C$ symmetric.
It can be shown that $U=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (A^T)^k C A^k$ converges, is symmetric and is the solution of the equation above.

Is it possible to show that if $C$ is non-negative also $U$ is non-negative?

Comment: In your infinite sum, all terms are nonnegative. Isn't this enough?

Comment: Federico Poloni is absolutely right.

Comment: Cleary if all the terms are nonnegative I am done, but the matrix $A$ could have negative entries, then how can I be sure that each term is nonnegative?

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "nonnegative"? Entrywise or positive semidefinite?

Comment: Entrywise. Now I doubt that the result holds, but I have not found a counter-examplet.

I agree that if C is semidefinite positive, then U is semidefinite positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach to solving the original equation.

The desired equation subject to the constraint $U \ge 0$ (elementwise nonnegativity) can be written as

\begin{equation*}
  U = C + A^TUA,\qquad U \ge 0.
\end{equation*}

Define now the iteration:

\begin{equation*}
  U_{k+1} = [C + A^TU_kA]_+,\qquad k=0,1,\ldots
\end{equation*}
where $[\cdot]_+ \equiv \max\lbrace 0, \cdot\rbrace$ denotes **projection** onto the nonnegative orthant. Assuming the slightly stronger condition that the operator norm $\|A\| < 1$, we can show that the above iteration converges to the desired solution.

$\newcommand{\Gc}{\mathcal{G}}$
**Claim.** Let $\Gc$ denote the map $U\mapsto [C + A^TUA]_+$. Then, $\Gc$ is a strict contraction in the spectral norm.

> *Proof.* Let $U, V$ be two matrices. Then,
>   \begin{eqnarray*}
> \|\Gc(U)-\Gc(V)\| &=& \|[C + A^TUA]_+ - [C + A^TVA]_+\|\\
> &\le& \|C + A^TUA - C - A^TVA]\|\\
> &\le& \|A^T(U-V)A\|\\
> &\le& \|A^T\| \|A\| \|U-V\| \\
> &\le& \gamma\|U-V\|,\qquad \text{where}\ \gamma=\|A\|^2 < 1.
> \end{eqnarray*}
>   The first inequality follows as projection is a *non-expansive* operator, the rest follow from obvious properties of the spectral norm.

Thus, $\Gc$ is a strict contraction. So by the Banach contraction theorem the iteration $U_{k+1}=\Gc(U_k)$ has a unique solution. This solution is nonnegative by construction and satisfies the desired equation.